# AppHarbor generates "The type or namespace name 'JQueryUIHelpers' could not be found...."

Tags: deployment, appharbor

I got a small app that works fine locally but when deployed to AppHarbor it generates an error shown in the title.. I remember having the some trouble locally when I first installed JqueryUi but I think that got solved after I restarted Visual Studio or something similar.. Have any of you maybe had a similar problem?

I have the namespace added in my `web.config`:

```
<namespaces>
        <add namespace="JQueryUIHelpers" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />.....
```

Here is the compiler output:

```
C:\Windows\SysWOW64\inetsrv> "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\csc.exe" /t:library /utf8output /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ServiceModel.Activities\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.ServiceModel.Activities.dll" /R:"D:\websites\da\7909c\18846\0x0001\_AspNetTemporaryFiles\root\94f6edf5\4b3c4129\assembly\dl3\404eafc3\6006998c_149ccf01\Raven.Client.Lightweight.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ServiceModel.Web\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.ServiceModel.Web.dll" /R:"D:\websites\da\7909c\18846\0x0001\_AspNetTemporaryFiles\root\94f6edf5\4b3c4129\assembly\dl3\7138b32b\3027d28c_149ccf01\System.Web.WebPages.Deployment.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Data.DataSetExtensions\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll" /R:"D:\websites\da\7909c\18846\0x0001\_AspNetTemporaryFiles\root\94f6edf5\4b3c4129\assembly\dl3\89cd7249\90e55f8c_149ccf01\Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.dll" /R:"D:\websites\da\7909c\18846\0x0001\_AspNetTemporaryFiles\root\94f6edf5\4b3c4129\assembly\dl3\62b95f03\32845d8c_149ccf01\Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.dll" /R:"D:\websites\da\7909c\18846\0x0001\_AspNetTemporaryFiles\root\94f6edf5\4b3c4129\assembly\dl3\fb8c6daa\4ca8648c_149ccf01\Microsoft.Owin.Security.Google.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ServiceModel.Activation\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.ServiceModel.Activation.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\System.Data\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.Extensions\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.Extensions.dll" /R:"D:\websites\da\7909c\18846\0x0001\_AspNetTemporaryFiles\root\94f6edf5\4b3c4129\assembly\dl3\20a4533f\32845d8c_149ccf01\Microsoft.Owin.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.CSharp\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.CSharp.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.WorkflowServices\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.WorkflowServices.dll" /R:"D:\websites\da\7909c\18846\0x0001\_AspNetTemporaryFiles\root\94f6edf5\4b3c4129\assembly\dl3\87b36314\ece9d68c_149ccf01\System.Web.WebPages.Razor.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\mscorlib.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xml.Linq\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xml.Linq.dll" /R:"D:\websites\da\7909c\18846\0x0001\_AspNetTemporaryFiles\root\94f6edf5\4b3c4129\assembly\dl3\49252b65\70fb858c_149ccf01\Newtonsoft.Json.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Runtime.Serialization\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Runtime.Serialization.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Core\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Core.dll" /R:"D:\websites\da\7909c\18846\0x0001\_AspNetTemporaryFiles\root\94f6edf5\4b3c4129\assembly\dl3\0d9f6c15\1e26298c_149ccf01\EntityFramework.dll" /R:"D:\websites\da\7909c\18846\0x0001\_AspNetTemporaryFiles\root\94f6edf5\4b3c4129\assembly\dl3\543b1400\76c1588c_149ccf01\Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.dll" /R:"D:\websites\da\7909c\18846\0x0001\_AspNetTemporaryFiles\root\94f6edf5\4b3c4129\assembly\dl3\589ff20b\8a1f8d8c_149ccf01\Raven.Abstractions.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.DynamicData\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.DynamicData.dll" /R:"D:\websites\da\7909c\18846\0x0001\_AspNetTemporaryFiles\root\94f6edf5\4b3c4129\assembly\dl3\fc957551\ee46628c_149ccf01\Microsoft.Owin.Security.dll" /R:"D:\websites\da\7909c\18846\0x0001\_AspNetTemporaryFiles\root\94f6edf5\4b3c4129\assembly\dl3\9bd44ba8\2cbe8a8c_149ccf01\Owin.dll" /R:"D:\websites\da\7909c\18846\0x0001\_AspNetTemporaryFiles\root\94f6edf5\4b3c4129\assembly\dl3\7e36e868\f2afa98c_149ccf01\System.Web.Helpers.dll" /R:"D:\websites\da\7909c\18846\0x0001\_AspNetTemporaryFiles\root\94f6edf5\4b3c4129\App_global.asax.3cvyzdd5.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ServiceModel\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.ServiceModel.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.IdentityModel\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.IdentityModel.dll" /R:"D:\websites\da\7909c\18846\0x0001\_AspNetTemporaryFiles\root\94f6edf5\4b3c4129\assembly\dl3\7a68e581\ae72ae8c_149ccf01\System.Web.Mvc.dll" /R:"D:\websites\da\7909c\18846\0x0001\_AspNetTemporaryFiles\root\94f6edf5\4b3c4129\assembly\dl3\29542930\aa09678c_149ccf01\Microsoft.Owin.Security.MicrosoftAccount.dll" /R:"D:\websites\da\7909c\18846\0x0001\_AspNetTemporaryFiles\root\94f6edf5\4b3c4129\assembly\dl3\53ef68df\1860568c_149ccf01\Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.WebPages.Deployment\v4.0_2.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.WebPages.Deployment.dll" /R:"D:\websites\da\7909c\18846\0x0001\_AspNetTemporaryFiles\root\94f6edf5\4b3c4129\assembly\dl3\f9bdca0d\4ca8648c_149ccf01\Microsoft.Owin.Security.Facebook.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure\v4.0_1.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure.dll" /R:"D:\websites\da\7909c\18846\0x0001\_AspNetTemporaryFiles\root\94f6edf5\4b3c4129\assembly\dl3\363589e5\66cc6b8c_149ccf01\Microsoft.Owin.Security.Twitter.dll" /R:"D:\websites\da\7909c\18846\0x0001\_AspNetTemporaryFiles\root\94f6edf5\4b3c4129\assembly\dl3\83282a8f\086b698c_149ccf01\Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Activities\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Activities.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Drawing\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Drawing.dll" /R:"D:\websites\da\7909c\18846\0x0001\_AspNetTemporaryFiles\root\94f6edf5\4b3c4129\assembly\dl3\314d6807\b6950c8c_149ccf01\aPhoto_web.dll" /R:"D:\websites\da\7909c\18846\0x0001\_AspNetTemporaryFiles\root\94f6edf5\4b3c4129\assembly\dl3\6edf7fb4\26f8b78c_149ccf01\System.Web.Optimization.dll" /R:"D:\websites\da\7909c\18846\0x0001\_AspNetTemporaryFiles\root\94f6edf5\4b3c4129\assembly\dl3\3005cea1\8e88d48c_149ccf01\System.Web.WebPages.dll" /R:"D:\websites\da\7909c\18846\0x0001\_AspNetTemporaryFiles\root\94f6edf5\4b3c4129\assembly\dl3\5092a3eb\401cbf8c_149ccf01\System.Web.Razor.dll" /R:"D:\websites\da\7909c\18846\0x0001\_AspNetTemporaryFiles\root\94f6edf5\4b3c4129\assembly\dl3\593a6b71\58340a8c_149ccf01\Antlr3.Runtime.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.ApplicationServices\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.ApplicationServices.dll" /R:"D:\websites\da\7909c\18846\0x0001\_AspNetTemporaryFiles\root\94f6edf5\4b3c4129\assembly\dl3\f2b6764b\6c923e8c_149ccf01\EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\System.EnterpriseServices\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.EnterpriseServices.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Configuration\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Configuration.dll" /R:"D:\websites\da\7909c\18846\0x0001\_AspNetTemporaryFiles\root\94f6edf5\4b3c4129\assembly\dl3\a41d28a0\646fe08c_149ccf01\WebGrease.dll" /R:"D:\websites\da\7909c\18846\0x0001\_AspNetTemporaryFiles\root\94f6edf5\4b3c4129\assembly\dl3\e9e2f7aa\d4225b8c_149ccf01\Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.WebPages.Deployment\v4.0_1.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.WebPages.Deployment.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\System.Web\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Web.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.Services\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Web.Services.dll" /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xml\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xml.dll" /out:"D:\websites\da\7909c\18846\0x0001\_AspNetTemporaryFiles\root\94f6edf5\4b3c4129\App_Web_index.cshtml.a8d08dba.r8ksypcy.dll" /D:DEBUG /debug+ /optimize- /w:4 /nowarn:1659;1699;1701;612;618 /warnaserror-  "D:\websites\da\7909c\18846\0x0001\_AspNetTemporaryFiles\root\94f6edf5\4b3c4129\App_Web_index.cshtml.a8d08dba.r8ksypcy.0.cs" "D:\websites\da\7909c\18846\0x0001\_AspNetTemporaryFiles\root\94f6edf5\4b3c4129\App_Web_index.cshtml.a8d08dba.r8ksypcy.1.cs"


    Microsoft (R) Visual C# Compiler version 4.0.30319.18408

    for Microsoft (R) .NET Framework 4.5
    Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

    d:\websites\da\7909c\18846\0x0001\_aspnettemporaryfiles\root\94f6edf5\4b3c4129\App_Web_index.cshtml.a8d08dba.r8ksypcy.0.cs(23,11): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'JQueryUIHelpers' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

Answer (score 0):

Appearently the **JqueryUI** targeted the **wrong version** of the **.NetFrameWork**.

Solution is to change the targeted .NET framework version in your web application. To do so,

1. Right click on the project
2. Click properties.
3. Click application tab from the left hand side (If it doesn't selected already)
4. Select the correct targeted .NET framework from the Drop-down menu.

**P.S.:**
*This answer was originally posted by the OP, in the question itself. I'm just posting it as an answer as I also got the same problem and solved it this way.*